# Single finger trackpad dragging inconsistent

Tags: touchpad, macbook

Since upgrading to Juno I've been having issues performing "drag" actions on the track pad. Examples include trying to drag windows, or dragging to select text on a webpage.

**Steps**

- Click and hold down the track pad.
- Drag while maintaining the above.

This should result in the window dragging, but often it just moves the mouse and doesn't actually *grab* the window / text.

If I use two fingers (e.g. one finger clicks and holds, and a second finger swipes the trackpad) the action works 100% of the time. This is inconvenient though, and wasn't occurring in Loki. It's not a track pad hardware issue as this action works great on MacOS which is on another partition.

I'm using a 2016 MacBook Pro.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If libinput driver installed by default feel too sensitive to point and click a small part of the screen,
 you can install synaptics driver instead.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

logout/in after package installation.

Comment: It's not too sensitive, it simply does not drag the windows when clicking and holding in the trackpad.